# APIRTC UserMediaError istrusted:false on Chrome at one location

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc

One user is getting this error when trying to initiate a call with APIRTC on Chrome.  I am assuming it is some kind of security restriction on their chrome installation.  I am also assuming other computers at the same facility will likely have the same problem.

Does anyone know what this error indicates and what setting is required in chrome or the code to fix it?

UserMediaError triggered by webRTCClient.call.  Error is istrusted:false.

Comment: `isTrusted` is an event attribute which is `true` only on genuine user interaction and `false` on fake events synthesized by a JS script.

Comment: I am aware of that he question is why is this specific event causing that error at this one installation? What security setting in chrome could be causing this?

Comment: AFAICT the definition of this attribute leaves only two possible explanations - an interfering extension or a bug in the browser.